# Analyzing a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

Do my analyze is correct? If don't then correct it.

> Sentence: The tsunami and the undersea earthquake which triggered it, the largest ever recorded in the region, killed nearly 20,000 people, destroyed over 100,000 homes and threw the lives of tens of millions into turmoil.

Subject: The tsunami and the undersea earthquake

Principal verb: triggered

Adjective clause of subject:the largest ever recorded in the region, killed nearly 20,000 people, destroyed over 100,000 homes

Use of parallelism:threw the lives of tens of millions into turmoil.

Comment: _Triggered_ is in a relative clause. The principal (not "principle") verbs are _killed_ and _threw_.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is "The tsunami and the undersea earthquake which triggered it"

There are three principal verbs, each have the same subject (which isn't repeated). The are  "killed", "destroyed" and "threw".  These three coordinated predicates are parallel to each other.

The phrase "which triggered it" is a relative clause describing the earthquake.

The phrase "the largest ever recorded in the region" is a parenthetical phrase giving extra information about the earthquake.